# Check if variable is float with max 2 decimal places

Tags: php, floating-point, money-format

I have user input in a script - `$_POST['money']` and I want to confirm that it is infact a float of 2 decimal places.

What I was planning would be `$money = (float)@$_POST['money']`, in this case it would set `$money` to zero if a non number was entered. But the case may occur when the user enters something like 5.234, in this case I would also want money set at zero.

I don't want to something tricky with `explode` or something like that, I was hoping there is an efficient way of doing this.

An integer is also fine, because it's a valid amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've chosen to use this code:

```
$money = (float)(@$_POST['money'] / 0.01) <> (int)(@$_POST['money'] / 0.01) ? 0 : (float)@$_POST['money'];
```

If you have a better solution please post.

Comment: Have chosen because it uses only maths, not other functions (except casting)

Comment: Only good enough if you are not interested in the number of places ... only don't like the use of `@`

Comment: @Baba: I am interested in the number of places, I've tested and this will only work with places <= 2, anything else will result in 0 which is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

check here:

http://php.net/manual/ro/function.is-float.php

and here

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

or use this function

```
function is_deccount($number,$decimal=2){
    $m_factor=pow(10,$decimal);
    if((int)($number*$m_factor)==$number*$m_factor)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure this will help. What I want to do is set `$money = 0` in any case where it is not a valid money amount, a case like `$_POST['money'] = 5.234` which is a valid float but is not money.